# Sharing Code Between Mobile and desktop version of ASP.NET C# Web Application (Forms)

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, web-applications, code-behind

I have an existing asp.net C# web application and I am starting to develop a mobile version by creating a sub folder "Mobile" and copying over the folders/files I will be offering on the mobile area. I have things working well with the differ style and sitemap for mobile.

As an example, there are many pages that will provide the same business processes, but there may be some slight changes to the presentation layer between the two, above and beyond the styles or master page.
I would like to share the code behind logic for the Login.aspx page between the mobile copy and the desktop copy.

I am fairly new using asp.net, so a simple example would be nice. I've tried to create a shared class in another folder, but have not been able to reference it properly and compile without errors.

Ideas?

Comment: I am not sure about your flexibility regarding the type of technology you can use, but MVC has built-in capability to handle web vs mobile output. In addition, by its very nature MVC separates the UI from the logic so that by default your web & mobile UIs will use the same code-base.

Comment: He's using web forms judging by the tags. It would be quite a task to convert an existing web forms site to MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Right mouse click on the project, then `Add ASP.NET Folder`, add "App_Code" folder and place the class there. After that you should be able to access that class throughout the project

Answer (score 0):

Separate your business logic into at least the App_Code folder. But preferably move it into its own class library project. Then add a reference from your website/web application project to the class library project. Here's how to do that: Right click your solution in the Solution Explorer, go to Add> New Project. Add a class library project to the solution from here. Then right click your Site project, click Add Reference, make sure you're on the Projects tab, and select the class library you previously created. Your business logic goes in the class library project, and your site-specific logic goes in the  website project. You need to add Using statements to your classes or use the full namespace syntax to access classes in the class library.

In your site-specific logic, you can have individual pages inherit from a common base class if the pages shares the same page specific logic.

```
 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
 //This is all the code behind logic for Default.aspx. This code is in Default.aspx.cs. Notice how it is inheriting from System.Web.UI.Page directly.
 }
```

change to this...

```
 public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
 //code common to multiple pages goes here. This file (BasePage.cs) goes in your App_Code folder.
 }
```

and this...

```
 public class _Default : BasePage
 {
 //Now your default page inherits from BasePage class, and therefore it indirectly inherits from System.Web.UI.Page.
 }
```

It's probably not a good idea to put .cs files into any folder besides App_Code. Code behind files (.aspx.cs and .aspx.vb) are the exception. See this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31557/A-Beginner-s-Guide-to-ASP-NET-Application-Folders for an explanation of App_Code and other special folders.

Comment: After trying the App_Code option, I actually used an existing "Classes" folder that are used by another class within my application.   But this code behind class I created I cannot get the system to recognize.

Comment: If I create a new base page for this (say LoginBase.aspx) and add all of the standard code in LoginBase.aspx.cs . Then create a Login.aspx and another in the /Mobile Folder . How do I get the latter two to inherit LoginBase.aspx.cs code behind?

Comment: @PGB did this end up working for you? (Remember to mark answers as accepted to help others)